# What constitutes an adjective phrase?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, participles, adjective-phrases

Participle phrase (which acts as an adjective )

prepositional phrase (which can be used as either an adverb phrase or an adjective phrase)

Q : So *adjective phrase* is just a fancy name that can be participle phrase or prepositional phrase and other modifier words, am I right?

Comment: Usage varies. In the grammatical sect I belong to (consisting, as far as I can tell, of me) a '{noun/participle/adjective/preposition/adverb} phrase' is a phrase whose 'head' is an actual {noun/participle/adjective/preposition/adverb}. When these  take syntactic roles corresponding to those typically played by {nouns/adjectives/adverbs} I refer to the use as '{nominal/adjectival/adverbial}'. What I thereby lose in intelligibility I gain in consistency.

Comment: I know what is phrase I just want to know whether participle phrase equal to adjective or not?

Comment: "I see a very thin man in shorts running fast". In my terminology *very thin* is an **adjective phrase**, *in shorts* is an **adjectival preposition phrase** and *running fast* is an **adjectival participle phrase**. It's trickier when an *-ing* form heads a phrase acting as a nominal ("Running fast is fun"); you could call *running fast* a **nominal participle phrase** but traditionally we call the *-ing* form a *gerund*, and this phrase a **gerund phrase**.

Comment: Without some examples it is difficult to talk about grammatical things. "Participle" means in Latin verb form  participating in two word classes. It is derived from a verb and can be used as a verb form or as an adjective. In "bathing girls" "bathing" acts as an adjective. In "mother, bathing her baby" "bathing"  has more verbal character. But I'm not sure whether this answers your question.

Comment: @rogermue More precisely, the participle may act in both roles simultaneously.

Comment: True @StoneyB, but perhaps we should simplify a bit for learners (laughing).

Comment: @rogermue Up to a point -- but simplifying can create confusion down the line. I bet a quarter of the questions we get here come about because questioners have been misled by early simplifications -- 'baby rules', I call them.

Comment: Your headline is very vague.